# Why does NMaximize miss this global maximum?

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I am having trouble maximizing a function which appears as a curvature of a planar curve.

```
{tmin, tmax} = {0, 2 Pi}

f = -((6-3 Cos[t] - Cos[3 t])/((-11+6 Cos[t] + 8 Cos[2 t] - 6 Cos[3 t] + Cos[4 t])
  Sqrt[Cos[t]^2 + 9 Sin[t]^2 - 12 Cos[t] Sin[t]^2 + 4 Cos[t]^2 Sin[t]^2]));

NMaximize[{f, tmin <= t <= tmax}, t]
```

says that the maximum of $f$ is attained at

```
{1.37888, {t -> 5.78352}}
```

But,

```
Plot[f, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: plot of f]

indicates that the true maximum is attained at $t=\pi$.

Why is this happening? 
I'm using Mathematica version 12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

Comment: Do not use [tag:bugs] as a tag until other people have confirmed what you see is a bug. In this case, it definitely isn't; `NMaximize[]` isn't always guaranteed to give a global optimum.

Comment: From the docs: "Otherwise, `NMaximize` may sometimes find only a local maximum."

Comment: In this case, `Maximize[{f, tmin <= t <= tmax}, t]` works.

Comment: @J. M., I see. Ill remove the tag "bug".

Comment: It only means that whenever possible, you should *always* check your answer. Here, you have the rare benefit of being able to plot the function being optimized; use it!

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I take your advice to heart.After COVID-19, I was using MMA for checking hundreds of "curvatures of parametrized curves" in my on-line vector-calculus class. This example was the first case which NMaximize couldn't find the true maximum.

Comment: @MarcoB, Thank you for editing my quesion.

Comment: @Michael E2, Thank you for letting me know "Maximize" works. I need to treat more complicated expression for f, so I used NMaximize rather than Maximize because I thought that this reduces the risk of missing the true maximum due to complexity of the expression. I realized I was wrong!

Comment: `NMaximize[{f, tmin <= t <= tmax}, t, Method -> "RandomSearch"]` produces `{5., {t -> 3.14159}}`.

Comment: So does `NMaximize[{f, tmin <= t <= tmax}, t, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]`.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you very much! That seems to be a very simple but robust way to get the right answer.

Comment: You can also use `NMaximize[{f, tmin <= t <= tmax}, t, 
 Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "SearchPoints" -> 15}]`, `NMaximize[{f, tmin <= t <= tmax}, t, 
 Method -> {"NelderMead", "InitialPoints" -> List /@ Subdivide[tmin, tmax, 5]}]` and so forth in addition to simulated annealing.  My question is how do you know it's more robust? How do you know it's even giving a correct answer? (In this example, you know the answer ahead of time, which is an unrealistic use-case — if you know the answer already, you wouldn't use `NMaximize` to find it.) In general global optimization is difficult.

Answer (score 15):

This kind of problem — smooth, univariate function over a finite and relatively small domain — can be handled numerically by using `NDSolve` to locate the relative maxima, polishing them with `FindMaximum`, and then selecting the greatest one:

```
MaximalBy[First]@
 With[{df2 = D[f, {t, 2}]},
  FindMaximum[{f, tmin <= t <= tmax}, {t, #}] & /@
   First@Last@Reap@NDSolve[
       {y'[t] == D[f, t], y[0] == 0,
        WhenEvent[y'[t] == 0 && df2 < 0, Sow[t]]},
       y, {t, tmin, tmax}]
  ]
```

> ```
> (*  {{5., {t -> 3.14159}}}  *)
> ```

[I'm sure this has been shown elsewhere on site, probably by me and several others.  This problem can in fact be done exactly by `Maximize`, but the OP suggests there are other cases that might need a numerical approach.]

Comment: Thank you very much for your neat code. I've been using MMA for a long time, but I have never used WhenEvent.

Answer (score 10):

Making use of `Method`, one obtains

```
NMaximize[{f, tmin <= t <= tmax}, t, Method -> "RandomSearch"]
(*{5., {t -> 3.14159}}*)
```

So does `Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That seems to be a very simple but robust way to get the right answer.

Comment: @A.Kato: Unfortunately,`Method->"DifferentialEvolution"` does not work here.

Answer (score 9):

Since your problem is single variable, we can also use Grid Search.

```
grid = Subdivide[2 π, 1000] // N;
val = f /@ grid;

Extract[#, Ordering[val, -1]] & /@ {val, grid}
```

> {5., 3.14159}

Alternatively, as suggested by @J.M., we can use `PeakDetect`

```
plot = Plot[f[t], {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotPoints -> 1000, PlotRange -> All];
points = Join @@ Cases[Normal@plot, Line[x_] :> x, ∞];
peaks = Pick[points, PeakDetect[points[[All, 2]]], 1];
MaximalBy[peaks, Last]
```

> {{3.14162, 5.}}

```
ListPlot[points, Epilog -> {Red, Point[peaks]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: You could systematize this by using `Plot[]`'s adaptive sampling along with `PeakDetect[]`.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to do as we do in calculus class. Find derivative, set to zero, find roots, find hessian, check sign. (not checking for saddle point :)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
{tmin, tmax} = {0, 2 Pi};
f = -((6 - 3 Cos[t] - 
       Cos[3 t])/((-11 + 6 Cos[t] + 8 Cos[2 t] - 6 Cos[3 t] + 
         Cos[4 t]) Sqrt[
        Cos[t]^2 + 9 Sin[t]^2 - 12 Cos[t] Sin[t]^2 + 
         4 Cos[t]^2 Sin[t]^2]));

diff    = D[f, t];
roots   = NSolve[diff == 0 && tmin <= t <= tmax, t]
hessian = D[f, {t, 2}] /. roots;
pts     = MapThread[{If[#2 > 0, Red, Blue], PointSize[0.02], 
            Point[{#1, f /. t -> #1}]} &, {t /. roots, hessian}];

Plot[f, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> pts, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
 PlotLabel->Row[{"Blue is local max, red is local min"}],BaseStyle->12]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

When `f` is not linear then [`NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) may return a local maximum.

```
{tmin, tmax} = {0, 2 Pi};

f = -((6 - 3 Cos[t] - 
       Cos[3 t])/((-11 + 6 Cos[t] + 8 Cos[2 t] - 6 Cos[3 t] + Cos[4 t]) Sqrt[
        Cos[t]^2 + 9 Sin[t]^2 - 12 Cos[t] Sin[t]^2 + 4 Cos[t]^2 Sin[t]^2]));
```

Find all of the maximum in the interval and select the largest.

```
max = SortBy[{f /. #, #} & /@ 
    NSolve[{D[f, t] == 0, D[f, {t, 2}] < 0, tmin <= t <= tmax}, t], 
  First] // Last

(* {5., {t -> 3.14159}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now understand that NMaximize is very close to FindMaximum. I wonder why they have different function names...

Comment: @A.Kato `FindMaximum[]` does not work as hard as `NMaximize[]`, since it's only intended to find a *local* optimum near the starting value you gave. By contrast, `NMaximize[]` works harder, because it **tries** (note the emphasis) to find a *global* optimum. Sometimes it works out, sometimes it doesn't. Here, you were just unlucky.